# Error saving rules in Firebase Storage

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-security, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload images in Firebase storage. I have been following [Firebase Storage Tutorial](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/firebase-storage-tutorial-android/) to upload images. As mentioned in the website, I have to change the default Storage rules. So, I changed the rules to :

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/fir-storage-42411.firebaseio.com/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

When I am trying to Publish the rules, I am getting the following error :

```
Error saving rules - Line 1: Parse error.
```

Tried to google the error, but could not find any result.

Thanks.

Comment: To allow read-write by everyone, use `allow read, write;` (so without the `if true`). See the [sample rules in the Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/start#sample-rules).

Comment: Still getting the same error

Comment: The impetus is on you to do the troubleshooting and find the relevant clues. "Still getting the same error" doesn't provide us any useful data to help you out here. It'll help to include all the relevant code, sample data, debug logging, and version info so we can fully understand the problem. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

The obvious error that I see is that your rules should reference your storage bucket (`fir-storage-42411.appspot.com`), not your database (`fir-storage-42411.firebaseio.com`). Beyond that, this should be valid (barring any hidden special characters that might be hidden there):

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/fir-storage-42411.appspot.com/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like this is something that is better handled over our 1:1 support channel, rather than via Stack Overflow. Mind creating a case @ https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/ so we can provide you more personalized assistance? It'll be easier to share screenshots/error messages there.